# Spring OAuth2 extract custom userinfo

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I'm trying to implement Spring OAuth2 with a custom provider. However, I'm having issues with `user-info-uri`. Our server returns userInfo inside an array and spring is unable to parse this response. This is a sample response returned by userInfo endpoint:

```json
{
 "status": 200,
 "users": [
           {
            "username": "username",
            "userId": "123",
             ...
            },
          ]
... some other keys
}
```

and in application.yaml

```
user-info-uri: https://api.myprovider.com/user
user-name-attribute: username
```

As you can see, the user info is inside an array. How can I make spring use users[0] as the userinfo and the `username` as the `user-name-attribute` ?